# once a branch executed other branches after it won't execute in oracle apex 20.1

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a list of branches in "After Process" point. Top one is a pl/sql code and then page redirect branches. But when I put pl/sql code branch into top of the list, plsql is executing but page redirect does not work. If I put the plsql after page redirect branches then page is redirecting without any issues but pl/sql not executed. My branches are listed as below,

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design - the first branch that meets true criteria will be branched to.

If you need PL/SQL executed, I would do that in the Processing section, after computations & validation.

I think the intention of 'Branch to PL/SQL Procedure' is just to defer the generation of the URL to PL/SQL - not to change data.

Answer (score 0):

Create branches

behavior : Function returning a page ( show only)

PL/SQL Function body:

```
declare
   vCondition number;
begin
   vCondition := 1;
   if (total > 0) then 
   --  Your process goes here...
   return '3';

  else 
   --  Your process goes here...
  return '1';
  end if;
end;
```